# Folder structure of scala+node.js web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, scala, web

I'm working on a small web-application with:

1. some static pages
2. some js code (most of it node.js e2e testing)
3. a scala server

what folder structure would you recommend? 
Should i separate the scala project from the html content and js code?
seems to me it should all be part of one project (which will later be one git repository) as the server will also retrieve the pages... 
Would appreciate any explained advise!